# What is the size of indexed image of 512*512 with 256 color values?

Tags: pixel, bmp

If I have an image of resolutin of 512 * 512,
and this image is indexed with 256 color values,
how to calulate the size of the image (file size ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image itself can be calculate as follow

256 can be stored in one byte. So one pixel is 1 byte.

You have a 512*512 pixels.

`512*512*1 = 262144` But on your disk, it will take a little more than those 262ko, as you have to count the bytes used for the file meta-information, and the color palette.

Check out the [bmp header spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#File_structure) if you need more informations.

Comment: but in this url
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color
if you see under the advnatage section
it's written 
truecolor uncompressed image needs 640×480×3 = 921,600 bytes (900 KiB). Limiting the image colors to 256, every pixel needs only 8 bits, or 1 byte each, so the example image now needs only 640×480×1 = 307,200 bytes (300 KiB), plus 256×3 = 768 additional bytes to store the palette map in itself (assuming RGB),

Comment: how to calculate the size of the pallete map ?

Comment: If you store rgb, you need 3 bytes per color. So `256 x 3` bytes. Count one more byte per color if you store alpha.

Comment: "Count one more byte per color if you store alpha"
could you give example to understand this ?